# How to add row numbers to rows added dynamically to a html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-table

I have a main view that has the following sample table definition.

```
<table id="myDynamicTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="964px">
        <thead>
            <tr id="uploadrow_0">
                <th" >
                    Number
                </th>
                <th">
                    Remarks
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model.myModel.Count > 0)
            {
                int i = 1;
                foreach (var item in Model.myModel)
                {
                    @Html.Partial("myModelPartial", item);
                     i += 1;
                }
            }
           else
            {
              @Html.Partial("myModelPartial", viewModel);
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I then have a partial view formatted like below

```
 @model myProject.ViewModel.mySampleViewModel
<tr>                
      @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("NewRow"))
      {             
        <td class="tdBorder">
              @if (Model.Number != 0)
              {
                 @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.Number)
              }
              else
              {
                @Html.Label("Number", "0")
              }
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Remark, new { id = "Remark"})
        </td>
      }       
</tr>
```

I'm using this partial view to dynamically add rows to a table in my main view & this part is working fine.

What i'm struggling with is adding the row numbers in the first column of the table i.e (Number column)

Below is how i'm adding the rows to the table in jquery `

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var tableBody = $('#myDynamicTable tbody');
        var url = '@Url.Action("Add", "Report")';
        $('#btnAddRow').click(function () {
            $.get(url, function (response) {
                tableBody.append(response);
                //auto number added rows
                $('#myDynamicTable tbody tr').each(function (idx) {
                    $(this).children(":eq(0)").html(idx + 1); //i'm trying to add the row number from here but this isn't working
                });
            });
        });
})`
```

Comment: Your script for renumbering the rows works fine (see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkjmzw63/1/)) but there is a lot of strange code in your question. Why do you have `int i = 1;` and `i += 1;` in the main view (you never use the value of `i`) and why do you have an `if` block in the partial and why does it create a `<label>` element (clicking on it wont set focus to the associated textbox because of the incorrect `for` attribute) - it can simply be `<td class="tdBorder">@Model.Number)</td>`.

Comment: And why are you setting `new { id = "Remark"}` which means your generating duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html?

Comment: @StephenMuecke i'm actually using the value of i, i just removed some code that i felt isn't necessary for this question.

Comment: Well the script works fine (as per the DotNetFiddle) so if its not working for you, I assume you have omitted other code which is relevant :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding `td:` got it working.

so this works

```
       //auto number added rows
        $('#myDynamicTable tbody tr').each(function (idx) {
            $(this).children("td:eq(0)").html(idx + 1);
        });
```

Ref: https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/